# inherit prototype to all child elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, inheritance

I want to add some functions to every DOM element, but I don't want to loop through all the elements. This is a demonstration code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    /* get the constructor of document, which is Document
       add the clickMe function to the prototype */
    document.constructor.prototype.clickMe = function (func) {
        this.addEventListener('click', function () {
            func();
        });
    };
    document.clickMe(clickDocument); // works

    /* doesn't work, because the prototype of document.getElementById('random_btn')
       does not have the function clickMe (makes sense) */
    document.getElementById('random_btn').clickMe(clickRandomBtn);
}

function clickDocument() {
    alert("clicked documet");
}

function clickRandomBtn() {
    alert("clicked a random button");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want this :

```
Element.prototype.clickMe = function (func) {
    this.addEventListener('click', function () {
        func();
    });
};
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/EdOGiGI/1/)

But changing the prototype of native objects is generally seen as a bad practice. See [Maintainable JavaScript: Don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was searching for.